# AppleScript error: "Mail got an error: Can’t set text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}."

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I have written an AppleScript that is activated by a mail rule whenever an email comes in that contains "+".

Why? I host my own mail server that allows for address tagging. What this means is that for example when I'm at a store and they ask for my email address, so they can email the receipt, I can give them my email address like this: whatmyemailnormallyis+nameofstore@domain.com. The applescript should then get the string between the "+" and "@" character, create a mailbox called "nameofstore" and move the message to it. Everything works fine except for I'm getting the following error:

"Mail got an error: Can’t set text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}."﻿

This is my script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set unreadmessages to the first message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Account"
    set theEmail to extract address from sender of item 1 of unreadmessages
    set mystring to theEmail
    set text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}
    set textlist to text items of mystring
    set mylist to {}
    repeat with i from 2 to count of textlist by 2
        set end of mylist to item i of textlist
    end repeat
    get mylist
    set mailboxName to mylist
    set messageAccount to account of (mailbox of item 1 of unreadmessages)
    set newMailbox to make new mailbox at (end of mailboxes of messageAccount) with properties {name:mailboxName}
    repeat with eachMessage in unreadmessages
        set mailbox of eachMessage to newMailbox
    end repeat
end tell
```

When I run only the text extract portion of the script it works fine:

```
set mystring to "whatmyemailnormallyis+nameofstore@domain.com"
set text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}
set textlist to text items of mystring
set mylist to {}
repeat with i from 2 to count of textlist by 2
    set end of mylist to item i of textlist
end repeat
get mylist
```

result:

```
{"nameofstore"}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anyone with better AppleScript skills than me can improve the script in other areas that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ...` instead of `set text item delimiters to ...`

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. But now I have a different issue, I have updated my original question. Thanks again!

Comment: RE: "But now I have a different issue, I have updated my original question. " --  That's not how this work here! You need to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks! I have opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540285/applescript-error-mail-got-an-error-unrecognized-direct-parameter-type-please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inheritance problem.  The property (`text item delimiters`) is a property of the `current application` (`AppleScript`) instance, but it's being referenced unqualified inside the `tell application` block that directs commands to and enumerates properties from the target application, in this case *Mail*.

The temptation might be to set the `text item delimiters` outside the `tell` block, by moving it from its current line position to just before the block declaration.  That's reasonable, but I think you've positioned it perfectly, as it's important (and good practice) to keep track of this property to ensure it's always appropriately set and, more significantly, never inappropriately not set.  The most reliable way to do this, which also makes it easier to follow for other people, is to do as you've done, which is to set the property immediately prior to any statement where it exerts influence (namely, any time a `list` is coerced to `text`, or `text` is split into `text items`).

So, to avoid shuffling lines of code around, we need to be able to make it clear to the compiler that the property that we're referencing doesn't belong to `application "Mail"`, but to the top-level scripting object, which will most typically be the `current application`.  The three ways to do this are:

- `set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ...`
- `set the current application's text item delimiters to ...`
- `set my text item delimiters to ...`

Stylistically, I favour the last option.  However, **`my`** is *not* a synonym for `current application` nor for `AppleScript`, but rather a reference to the parent of your script.  Unless the `parent` property is specifically declared in your script, then it will default to `current application`.  However, there are reasons one might choose to assign a different value, in which case only the first or second of the above three options will be viable.

---

Here's a slight reworking of your script, which I'm afraid you'll have to test in lieu of my purchase of a new MacBook.  I noticed some oddities in yours:

- You obtain the `first message` in the inbox, but on the next line, reference `item 1...` of, what I imagine you thought would be a `list` of messages, but would in fact be a single `message` class object.
- This single `message` object is the only message your script utilises to process the sender's email address.  However, later on, you loop through, again, what you expect to be a collection of inbox messages, which, if it were, may not all have the same `+` tag.
- You loopp through the `text items` generated by splitting the email address, and quite smartly start at index 2, and skip over every other item in the list.  However, this list will only have three items in it, so there's never any looping to be done, and you can simply make use of `text item 2`.
- In creating a new mailbox, you didn't first check to see if the mailbox already exists.  I'm not sure whether *Mail* would throw an error, or silently ignore this.  But I've redrafted the line to check first, and create if necessary.
- Lastly, the final repeat loop is presently not necessary given `unreadmessages` is not a list (so might actually throw an error).  So I removed the loop construct, but otherwise kept the line as it was.  I'm not sure whether the `mailbox` property of a `message` is one that can be set, i.e. it might be read-only.  If this is the case, that will throw an error, and you'll have to invoke the **`move`** command in order to move a message to a new mailbox.  I may be wrong, though, and it may work just the way you intended.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set firstInboxMessage to the first message in the inbox
    set theEmail to extract address from sender of the firstInboxMessage

    set my text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}
    -- Since the script will trigger only when an email address
    -- contains "+", we know text item 2 will always exist and
    -- will always represent the slice of text we're after
    set mailboxName to text item 2 of theEmail

    set messageAccount to account of mailbox of the firstInboxMessage
    tell the messageAccount to if the name of its mailboxes does not contain ¬
        the mailboxName then make new mailbox at the end of its mailboxes ¬
        with properties {name:mailboxName}
    set newMailbox to the mailbox named mailboxName in the messageAccount
    set the mailbox of the firstInboxMessage to the newMailbox
end tell
```

In reality, if you're invoking this script as a mail rule, you'll probably want to enclose this within the special handler that you can look up in the *Mail* scripting dictionary, called something like **`on receiving messages <messages> for mailbox rule <rule>`**

Comment: Thanks for this, very insightful! I had edited my script myself to simplify it (with the help of others) but I think your approach is so much more elegant. but I made a mistake in my original script. The string shouldn't be extracted from the sender email address but rather from the recipient email address. When I substitute sender for to recipient I get the following error: Mail got an error: Unrecognized direct parameter type, please specify a string like "John Doe <jdoe@example.com>". Any idea?

Comment: I have opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68540285/applescript-error-mail-got-an-error-unrecognized-direct-parameter-type-please

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your comments, and I see you've had the issue resolved pretty speedily, which is great.  Thanks as well for the green tick.