# AppleScript Error: Mail got an error: Unrecognized direct parameter type, please specify a string like "John Doe <jdoe@example.com>"

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I have a script that filters emails based on the `to recipient` but I'm getting an error.

This is the script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set firstInboxMessage to the first message of mailbox "INBOX" of account "Account"
    set theEmail to extract address from to recipient of the firstInboxMessage
    set my text item delimiters to {"+", "@"}
    set mailboxName to text item 2 of theEmail
    set messageAccount to account of mailbox of the firstInboxMessage
    tell the messageAccount to if the name of its mailboxes does not contain ¬
        the mailboxName then make new mailbox at the end of its mailboxes ¬
        with properties {name:mailboxName}
    set newMailbox to the mailbox named mailboxName in the messageAccount
    set the mailbox of the firstInboxMessage to the newMailbox
end tell
```

And this is the error:

```
Mail got an error: Unrecognized direct parameter type, please specify a string like "John Doe <jdoe@example.com>"
```

I think it has to do with the fact that `to recipient` is classified differently somehow in AppleScript compared to for example `subject` or `sender` because when I use either of those the script runs fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `to recipient` is an element. There can be more than one recipient.
2. The address of `to recipient` is available in the `address` property, `extract address from` is not needed. To clarify it: `extract address from` applied to `John Doe <jdoe@example.com>` returns `jdoe@example.com` but a `to recipient` doesn't contain such a compounded string.

Simply write

```
set theEmail to address of to recipient 1 of the firstInboxMessage
```